# setting highcharts title in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

how do i set a title of highcharts from an element?

here is my code:

```
$(function () {
var chart;

$('#second-chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Assortment # by SKUs'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Lazada', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '# of SKUs'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'SKU',
        data: [500, 120, 150, 300]
    }]
});

chart = $('#container').highcharts();

$('#chart-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var title_string = $(this).closest('.row').find('.form-control').val().toString();
    chart.setTitle({ text: title_string});
    // alert(title_string);
});

});
```

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omp4b291/

what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your modal code you need to make use of parent() instead of children in order to access the textControl.

And when deciding on the highCharts, you have to map it with second-chart as you already defined that one only and since there is no #container you need to have that in one which is in your markup

Here is a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omp4b291/1/)

Code Snippet

```
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $('#second-chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Assortment # by SKUs'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Lazada', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '# of SKUs'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'SKU',
            data: [500, 120, 150, 300]
        }]
    });

    $('#chart-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
         var chart = $('#second-chart').highcharts();
        var title_string = $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val().toString();
        console.log(chart);
        chart.setTitle({ text: title_string});
    });

});
```

Comment: wow thanks! i am targeting the wrong elements... thanks for not only answering but you've explained it as well..